# Create MKPlacemark/CLPlacemark from human-readable string

Tags: mapkit, clplacemark, mkplacemark

Is there a way to create a `MKPlacemark` from a human-readable string, e.g. the placemark's own `description`?

```
placemark.description // -> "The Home Depot, 1675 Wilshire Blvd, Los Angeles, CA  90017, United States @ <+34.05726385,-118.27165514> +/- 0.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:\'<+34.05726385,-118.27165514> radius 141.68\', center:<+34.05726385,-118.27165514>, radius:141.68m)"
```

I am aware of `NSKeyedArchiver`, but as far as I can tell its output is not readable.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out what I want is called forward-geocoding, and is supported by the `CLGeocoder` class.

```
let addressString = "123 Somewhere Pl"
CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(addressString) { placemark, _ in
    guard let placemark = placemark else { return }
    // use placemark...
}
```